# add an extra line to a table based on absence from other list

Tags: r, merge

I was wondering if it is possible to add an extra line to a table based on the absence of a certain value from another table. This is how my situation looks like

Text file with 2 columns

```
V1 V2
1  100
1  101
1  102
1  103
2  230
2  231
2  232
... ...
```

Other text file with 5 columns

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  100 a b c
1  101 a b c
1  103 a b c
2  231 a b c
2  232 a b c
```

When the combination of values from V1 & V2 of the first textfile is NOT present in the second text file (in the example 1 102 and 2 230 are not present), I want to add extra lines in the second file with the value of V1 and V2 from the first file & with V3,V4 and V5 equal to 0

So that the second file becomes like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  100 a b c
1  101 a b c
1  102 0 0 0
1  103 a b c
2  230 0 0 0
2  231 a b c
2  232 a b c
```

I cannot find the right command to do this in R. Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two objects are named "DF1" and "DF2", you can use `merge` as follows:

```
DFM <- merge(DF1, DF2, all = TRUE)
DFM
#   V1  V2   V3   V4   V5
# 1  1 100    a    b    c
# 2  1 101    a    b    c
# 3  1 102 <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4  1 103    a    b    c
# 5  2 230 <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 6  2 231    a    b    c
# 7  2 232    a    b    c
```

If you would really prefer `0` instead of `NA`, you can do the following:

```
# Convert the factors to characters
DFM[sapply(DFM, is.factor)] <- lapply(DFM[sapply(DFM, is.factor)], as.character)
# Identify the NA values and replace them with 0
DFM[is.na(DFM)] <- 0
DFM
#   V1  V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1  1 100  a  b  c
# 2  1 101  a  b  c
# 3  1 102  0  0  0
# 4  1 103  a  b  c
# 5  2 230  0  0  0
# 6  2 231  a  b  c
# 7  2 232  a  b  c
```